# How to solve geopandas execution problem in python?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

my first question of python...

I don't know why import geopandas is refused.

import geopandas as gpd

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41fbbe699a55> in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import pandas as pd
----> 7 import geopandas as gpd
      8 from geopy.distance import distance, lonlat
      9 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
      4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from geopandas.plotting import plot_series
---> 12 from geopandas.base import GeoPandasBase, _series_unary_op, _CoordinateIndexer
     13 
     14 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py in <module>
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 from pandas import Series, DataFrame, MultiIndex
----> 6 from pandas.core.indexing import _NDFrameIndexer
      7 from shapely.geometry import box, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon
      8 from shapely.ops import cascaded_union, unary_union

ImportError: cannot import name '_NDFrameIndexer' from 'pandas.core.indexing'                         
(C:\Users\OWNER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py)
```

I don't know how to do solve this problem

help me...

Comment: Which version of pandas and geopandas do you have? `conda list` will show that.

Comment: geopandas is 0.4.1  and pandas is 1.1.0

Comment: GeoPandas 0.4.1 is outdated and will not play well with pandas 1.1.0. You should update to geopandas 0.8.1.

Comment: i love you... I spend my precious 3 hour to solve this problem.. your answer is best answer